# Switch state using intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-switch

Hello everyone from more a week I am facing a problem that when I change the switch in activity 1 then when I switch to another activity then i.e: activity 2 using intent the switch compact state which we had changed in activity 1 is reflecting activity 2 I think this is the problem of intent so far I use the shared preference to save the state no problem with my shared preference.

UtilMainActivity

```
public class UtilMainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

SwitchCompat onOffSwitch;
TextView firstAlarmTextView;
TextView timeLeftTextView;
LinearLayout firstAlarmLayout;
UtilSharedPreferencesHelper sharPrefHelper;
UtilTimerManager utilTimerManager;
UtilAlarmParams utilAlarmParams;
BroadcastReceiver timeLeftReceiver;
private final String LOG_TAG = UtilMainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

final int ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 45;
final float DISPLAYED_NUMBERS_SIZE_RELATIVE_TO_TEXT_PROPORTION = 2f;  // number of alarms, first alarm, interval values text size is larger than text around them

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.utility_activity_main);
    onOffSwitch = (SwitchCompat) findViewById(R.id.switch_main);
    firstAlarmLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_main_firstalarm);
    firstAlarmTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_main_firstalarm_time);
    timeLeftTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_main_timeleft);

    sharPrefHelper = new UtilSharedPreferencesHelper(UtilMainActivity.this);
    sharPrefHelper.printAll();

    utilAlarmParams = sharPrefHelper.utilgetParams();
    utilTimerManager = new UtilTimerManager(UtilMainActivity.this);

    showFirstAlarmTime(utilAlarmParams.firstUtilAlarmTime.toString());
    showTimeLeft(utilAlarmParams);

    onOffSwitch.setChecked(sharPrefHelper.isAlarmTurnedOn());


    onOffSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            utilAlarmParams.turnedOn = isChecked;
            if (isChecked) {
                checkNotificationPolicy();
                checkOverlayPermission();
                utilTimerManager.startSingleAlarmTimer(utilAlarmParams.firstUtilAlarmTime.toMillis());
                showToast(getString(R.string.utility_main_alarm_turned_on_toast));
            } else {
                utilTimerManager.cancelTimer();
                showToast(getString(R.string.utility_main_alarm_turned_off_toast));
            }
            showTimeLeft(utilAlarmParams);
            sharPrefHelper.utilsetAlarmState(isChecked);
        }
    });


    firstAlarmLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Bundle timePickerBundle = new Bundle();
            timePickerBundle.putInt(UtilTimePickerDialogFragment.BUNDLE_KEY_ALARM_HOUR, sharPrefHelper.utilgetHour());
            timePickerBundle.putInt(UtilTimePickerDialogFragment.BUNDLE_KEY_ALARM_MINUTE, sharPrefHelper.utilgetMinute());

            UtilTimePickerDialogFragment timePicker = new UtilTimePickerDialogFragment();

            timePicker.setArguments(timePickerBundle);
            timePicker.show(getFragmentManager(), UtilTimePickerDialogFragment.FRAGMENT_TAG);
        }
    });

}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    showTimeLeft(utilAlarmParams);
    timeLeftReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().compareTo(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK) == 0) {  //i.e. every minute
                showTimeLeft(utilAlarmParams);
            }
        }
    };
    registerReceiver(timeLeftReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK));
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (timeLeftReceiver != null) {
        unregisterReceiver(timeLeftReceiver);
    }
}
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hour, int minute) {
    UtilAlarmTime utilAlarmTime = new UtilAlarmTime(hour, minute);
    utilAlarmParams.firstUtilAlarmTime = utilAlarmTime;
    showFirstAlarmTime(utilAlarmTime.toString());
    showTimeLeft(utilAlarmParams);
    resetTimerIfTurnedOn();
    sharPrefHelper.utilsetTime(utilAlarmTime);
}

private void showToast(String message) {
    Toast.makeText(UtilMainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private void resetTimerIfTurnedOn() {
    if (onOffSwitch.isChecked()) {
        utilTimerManager.resetSingleAlarmTimer(utilAlarmParams.firstUtilAlarmTime.toMillis());
        showToast(getString(R.string.utility_main_alarm_reset_toast));
    }
}


private void showFirstAlarmTime(String firstAlarmTime) {
    String wholeTitle = getString(R.string.utility_main_firstalarm_time, firstAlarmTime);
    SpannableString wholeTitleSpan = new SpannableString(wholeTitle);
    wholeTitleSpan.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(DISPLAYED_NUMBERS_SIZE_RELATIVE_TO_TEXT_PROPORTION),
            wholeTitle.indexOf(firstAlarmTime) - 1,
            wholeTitle.indexOf(firstAlarmTime) + firstAlarmTime.length(), 0);
    firstAlarmTextView.setText(wholeTitleSpan);
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private void showTimeLeft(UtilAlarmParams utilAlarmParams) {
    UtilAlarmTime utilAlarmTime = utilAlarmParams.firstUtilAlarmTime;
    timeLeftTextView.setText(getString(R.string.utility_all_time_left, utilAlarmTime.getHoursLeft(), utilAlarmTime.getMinutesLeft()));
    if (utilAlarmParams.turnedOn) {
        timeLeftTextView.setTextColor(getColor(R.color.primary));
    } else {
        timeLeftTextView.setTextColor(getColor(R.color.main_disabled_textcolor));
    }
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Time left: "+ utilAlarmTime.getHoursLeft() + ":" + utilAlarmTime.getMinutesLeft());
}

private void checkNotificationPolicy() {
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M
            && !notificationManager.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(
                android.provider.Settings
                        .ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

/**
 * needed for Android Q: on some devices activity doesn't show from fullScreenNotification without
 * permission SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW
 */
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private void checkOverlayPermission() {
    if ((Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.P) && (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this))) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                Uri.parse("package:" + this.getPackageName()));
        startActivityForResult(intent, ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}
}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    IntervalDialogFragment.IntervalDialogListener,
    NumberOfAlarmsDialogFragment.NumberOfAlarmsDialogListener,
    TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

SwitchCompat onOffSwitch;
ListView alarmsListView;
TextView intervalBetweenAlarmsTextView;
TextView numberOfAlarmsTextView;
TextView firstAlarmTextView;
TextView timeLeftTextView;
LinearLayout firstAlarmLayout;
LinearLayout intervalLayout;
LinearLayout numberOfAlarmsLayout;
AlarmsListHelper alarmsListHelper;
SharedPreferencesHelper sharPrefHelper;
TimerManager timerManager;
AlarmParams alarmParams;
BroadcastReceiver timeLeftReceiver;
Button sleepTimer;
private final String LOG_TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

final int ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 45;
final float DISPLAYED_NUMBERS_SIZE_RELATIVE_TO_TEXT_PROPORTION = 2f;  // number of alarms, first alarm, interval values text size is larger than text around them

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    alarmsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_main_alarmslist);
    onOffSwitch = (SwitchCompat) findViewById(R.id.util_switch_main);
    intervalBetweenAlarmsTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_main_interval);
    numberOfAlarmsTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_main_numberofalarms);
    firstAlarmLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_main_firstalarm);
    firstAlarmTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.util_textview_main_firstalarm_time);
    timeLeftTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_main_timeleft);
    intervalLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_main_interval);
    numberOfAlarmsLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_main_numberofalarms);
    sleepTimer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sleepTimer);

    sharPrefHelper = new SharedPreferencesHelper(MainActivity.this);
    sharPrefHelper.printAll();

    alarmParams = sharPrefHelper.getParams();
    timerManager = new TimerManager(MainActivity.this);
    alarmsListHelper = new AlarmsListHelper(MainActivity.this, alarmsListView);

    showFirstAlarmTime(alarmParams.firstAlarmTime.toString());
    showTimeLeft(alarmParams);

    showInterval(sharPrefHelper.getIntervalStr());
    showNumberOfAlarms(sharPrefHelper.getNumberOfAlarmsStr());
    onOffSwitch.setChecked(sharPrefHelper.isAlarmTurnedOn());

    alarmsListHelper.showList(alarmParams);

    onOffSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            alarmParams.turnedOn = isChecked;
            if (isChecked) {
                checkNotificationPolicy();
                checkOverlayPermission();
                timerManager.startSingleAlarmTimer(alarmParams.firstAlarmTime.toMillis());
                showToast(getString(R.string.main_alarm_turned_on_toast));
                sharPrefHelper.setNumberOfAlreadyRangAlarms(0);
            } else {
                timerManager.cancelTimer();
                showToast(getString(R.string.main_alarm_turned_off_toast));
            }
            alarmsListHelper.showList(alarmParams);
            showTimeLeft(alarmParams);
            sharPrefHelper.setAlarmState(isChecked);
        }
    });

    intervalLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            IntervalDialogFragment dialog = new IntervalDialogFragment();
            Bundle intervalBundle = new Bundle();
            intervalBundle.putString(IntervalDialogFragment.BUNDLE_KEY_INTERVAL, sharPrefHelper.getIntervalStr());
            dialog.setArguments(intervalBundle);
            dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), IntervalDialogFragment.FRAGMENT_TAG);
        }
    });

    numberOfAlarmsLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            NumberOfAlarmsDialogFragment dialog = new NumberOfAlarmsDialogFragment();
            Bundle numberOfAlarmsBundle = new Bundle();
            numberOfAlarmsBundle.putString(NumberOfAlarmsDialogFragment.BUNDLE_KEY_NUMBER_OF_ALARMS, sharPrefHelper.getNumberOfAlarmsStr());
            dialog.setArguments(numberOfAlarmsBundle);
            dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), NumberOfAlarmsDialogFragment.FRAGMENT_TAG);
        }
    });

    firstAlarmLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Bundle timePickerBundle = new Bundle();
            timePickerBundle.putInt(TimePickerDialogFragment.BUNDLE_KEY_ALARM_HOUR, sharPrefHelper.getHour());
            timePickerBundle.putInt(TimePickerDialogFragment.BUNDLE_KEY_ALARM_MINUTE, sharPrefHelper.getMinute());

            TimePickerDialogFragment timePicker = new TimePickerDialogFragment();

            timePicker.setArguments(timePickerBundle);
            timePicker.show(getFragmentManager(), TimePickerDialogFragment.FRAGMENT_TAG);
        }
    });

    sleepTimer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openNewActivity();
        }
    });


}
public void openNewActivity(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SleepTimerActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    showTimeLeft(alarmParams);
    timeLeftReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().compareTo(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK) == 0) {  //i.e. every minute
                showTimeLeft(alarmParams);
            }
        }
    };
    registerReceiver(timeLeftReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK));
}



@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (timeLeftReceiver != null) {
        unregisterReceiver(timeLeftReceiver);
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final View view = findViewById(R.id.scheduleactivity);

            if (view != null) {
                view.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                        // Do something...

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Scheduled Utilities Stopper", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.action_settings: {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, PrefActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        }
        case R.id.scheduleactivity: {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, UtilMainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@Override
public void onIntervalChanged(String intervalStr) {
    showInterval(intervalStr);
    alarmParams.interval = Integer.parseInt(intervalStr);
    alarmsListHelper.showList(alarmParams);
    resetTimerIfTurnedOn();
    sharPrefHelper.setInterval(intervalStr);
}

@Override
public void onNumberOfAlarmsChanged(String numberOfAlarmsStr) {
    showNumberOfAlarms(numberOfAlarmsStr);
    alarmParams.numberOfAlarms = Integer.parseInt(numberOfAlarmsStr);
    alarmsListHelper.showList(alarmParams);
    resetTimerIfTurnedOn();
    sharPrefHelper.setNumberOfAlarms(numberOfAlarmsStr);
}

@Override
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hour, int minute) {
    AlarmTime alarmTime = new AlarmTime(hour, minute);
    alarmParams.firstAlarmTime = alarmTime;
    showFirstAlarmTime(alarmTime.toString());
    alarmsListHelper.showList(alarmParams);
    showTimeLeft(alarmParams);
    sharPrefHelper.setNumberOfAlreadyRangAlarms(0);
    resetTimerIfTurnedOn();
    sharPrefHelper.setTime(alarmTime);
}

private void showToast(String message) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private void resetTimerIfTurnedOn() {
    if (onOffSwitch.isChecked()) {
        timerManager.resetSingleAlarmTimer(alarmParams.firstAlarmTime.toMillis());
        showToast(getString(R.string.main_alarm_reset_toast));
    }
}

private void showInterval(String interval) {
    String wholeTitle = getString(R.string.main_interval, interval);
    SpannableString wholeTitleSpan = new SpannableString(wholeTitle);
    wholeTitleSpan.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(DISPLAYED_NUMBERS_SIZE_RELATIVE_TO_TEXT_PROPORTION), wholeTitle.indexOf(interval), interval.length() + 1, 0);
    intervalBetweenAlarmsTextView.setText(wholeTitleSpan);
}

private void showNumberOfAlarms(String numberOfAlarms) {
    int numberOfAlarmsInt = Integer.parseInt(numberOfAlarms);
    String wholeTitle = this.getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.main_number_of_alarms, numberOfAlarmsInt, numberOfAlarmsInt);
    SpannableString wholeTitleSpan = new SpannableString(wholeTitle);
    wholeTitleSpan.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(DISPLAYED_NUMBERS_SIZE_RELATIVE_TO_TEXT_PROPORTION),
            wholeTitle.indexOf(numberOfAlarms),
            numberOfAlarms.length() + 1, 0);
    numberOfAlarmsTextView.setText(wholeTitleSpan);
}

private void showFirstAlarmTime(String firstAlarmTime) {
    String wholeTitle = getString(R.string.main_firstalarm_time, firstAlarmTime);
    SpannableString wholeTitleSpan = new SpannableString(wholeTitle);
    wholeTitleSpan.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(DISPLAYED_NUMBERS_SIZE_RELATIVE_TO_TEXT_PROPORTION),
            wholeTitle.indexOf(firstAlarmTime) - 1,
            wholeTitle.indexOf(firstAlarmTime) + firstAlarmTime.length(), 0);
    firstAlarmTextView.setText(wholeTitleSpan);
}

private void showTimeLeft(AlarmParams alarmParams) {
    AlarmTime alarmTime = alarmParams.firstAlarmTime;
    timeLeftTextView.setText(getString(R.string.all_time_left, alarmTime.getHoursLeft(), alarmTime.getMinutesLeft()));
    if (alarmParams.turnedOn) {
        timeLeftTextView.setTextColor(getColor(R.color.primary));
    } else {
        timeLeftTextView.setTextColor(getColor(R.color.main_disabled_textcolor));
    }
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Time left: "+alarmTime.getHoursLeft() + ":" + alarmTime.getMinutesLeft());
}

private void checkNotificationPolicy() {
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M
            && !notificationManager.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(
                android.provider.Settings
                        .ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

/**
 * needed for Android Q: on some devices activity doesn't show from fullScreenNotification without
 * permission SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW
 */
private void checkOverlayPermission() {
    if ((Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.P) && (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this))) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                Uri.parse("package:" + this.getPackageName()));
        startActivityForResult(intent, ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Post some of your code, The code for the Intent, and prefrences etc. We cant diagnose if we dont have anycode

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing your original post with any new information you have, any new code you've tried, or an explanation of why any posted answers aren't working, will bump it to the top of the active queue.

Comment: i had edited it

Comment: The question is shown to you above should answer you question,just something I noticed , you should add a onDestroy method and clear the shared prefrences in it, this should stop the app from having the saved prefrences still saved on launch which could cause the issues you are decribing

Comment: will i lose that in my activity 1 toooo

Comment: No if you do onDestroy, it will only clear when the app/Activity is closed completely. so on app exit etc. I had the same issue with values staying in activities, but on desstroy makes them go away, but switching to antoher activity does not destroy the activity, its still there in the background as when you press the back button you will go back to said activity

Comment: its bit of a slog and heavy reading and stuff but check here https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

knowing how thelifecycles of activities in android work is a core part of making apps

Comment: because what can happen when debugging an app some data is cached and thats why it still shows on activity